# How can I adjust the size of my pgf plot and get rid of these colours

Tags: pgfplots

I am having too much trouble trying to get a nice looking plot that takes latex font with gnuplot so I am trying pgfplots again.

The only trouble is that I cannot resize the plot, so that it fills half the page. I would also like the points to be smaller and don't know how to make it so. I would also like to not have to paste the data twice to get it to work. I cannot pull it from a file because pgplots seems to need titles and my file format has not the titles in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:18]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Current $mA$}, ylabel={Voltage $mV$}]

\addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter src=\thisrow{Current},
      error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, y explicit, x explicit, error bar style={color=mapped color}]
      table[x=Current,y=Voltage,x error=xerr,y error=yerr] {
Current Voltage xerr   yerr     
13.9900 -1.80000 0.149900 0.197300 
12.0200 -1.50000 0.130200 0.197750 
9.99000 -1.30000 0.109900 0.198050 
8.00000 -1.00000 0.0900000 0.198500 
6.02000 -0.800000 0.0702000 0.198800 
4.01000 -0.500000 0.0501000 0.199250 
2.00000 -0.300000 0.0300000 0.199550 
0.00000 0.00000 0.0100000 0.200000 
-2.00000 0.300000 -0.0100000 0.200450 
-4.00000 0.500000 -0.0300000 0.200750 
-6.02000 0.800000 -0.0502000 0.201200 
-8.00000 1.10000 -0.0700000 0.201650 
-10.0000 1.30000 -0.0900000 0.201950 
-12.0300 1.50000 -0.110300 0.202250 
-13.9800 1.80000 -0.129800 0.202700 
};
   \addplot[no markers,color=blue,forget plot] table [x=Current, y={create col/linear regression={y=Voltage}}]{
   Current Voltage xerr   yerr     
13.9900 -1.80000 0.149900 0.197300 
12.0200 -1.50000 0.130200 0.197750 
9.99000 -1.30000 0.109900 0.198050 
8.00000 -1.00000 0.0900000 0.198500 
6.02000 -0.800000 0.0702000 0.198800 
4.01000 -0.500000 0.0501000 0.199250 
2.00000 -0.300000 0.0300000 0.199550 
0.00000 0.00000 0.0100000 0.200000 
-2.00000 0.300000 -0.0100000 0.200450 
-4.00000 0.500000 -0.0300000 0.200750 
-6.02000 0.800000 -0.0502000 0.201200 
-8.00000 1.10000 -0.0700000 0.201650 
-10.0000 1.30000 -0.0900000 0.201950 
-12.0300 1.50000 -0.110300 0.202250 
-13.9800 1.80000 -0.129800 0.202700 
}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

Update: When trying the method below: This is the file:

```
13.9600 -7.60000 0.149600 0.188600 
12.0100 -6.50000 0.130100 0.190250 
9.98000 -5.40000 0.109800 0.191900 
7.99000 -4.30000 0.0899000 0.193550 
6.01000 -3.30000 0.0701000 0.195050 
4.00000 -2.20000 0.0500000 0.196700 
2.00000 -1.10000 0.0300000 0.198350 
0.00000 0.00000 0.0100000 0.200000 
-2.00000 1.10000 -0.0100000 0.201650 
-3.99000 2.20000 -0.0299000 0.203300 
-6.01000 3.20000 -0.0501000 0.204800 
-7.99000 4.30000 -0.0699000 0.206450 
-9.99000 5.40000 -0.0899000 0.208100 
-12.0000 6.40000 -0.110000 0.209600 
-13.9700 7.50000 -0.129700 0.211250
```

[image: graphoutcome]

[image]

Comment: Put your data between `\pgfplotstableread{.....}{\mytable}` and use that for consecutive uses. Also look for `header=false`,`height=...` options.

Comment: Is this an answer? I've dome something but I am not sure what you mean about the header stuff,

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{filecontents}` and `\begin{filecontentes}{wfn.dat}` and `\end{filecontents}`. That package is only needed for creating example problems, when you need to include an external file in the example `.tex` document. If the file `wfn.dat` exists on your file system, you don't need `filecontents`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. PGFPlots does not require data files to have headers. If there are no headers, you can refer to the columns using `x index=<column number>`, `x error=<column number>`, etc. In the `linear regression` options, you can set `y=1` to refer to the second column.
2. To resize the plot, you can specify the `height` and/or `width` of the plot. If you only specify one of these, the aspect ratio will be kept constant, and the plot will just be scaled. If you specify both, the aspect ratio changes.
3. If you want the data points to be smaller, set `mark size=1.5` (or something like that).
4. If you don't want colours for the markers (as your question title suggests), don't use `scatter`, just use `only marks`.

[image]

A file `data.csv`:

```
13.9900 -1.80000 0.149900 0.197300 
12.0200 -1.50000 0.130200 0.197750 
9.99000 -1.30000 0.109900 0.198050 
8.00000 -1.00000 0.0900000 0.198500 
6.02000 -0.800000 0.0702000 0.198800 
4.01000 -0.500000 0.0501000 0.199250 
2.00000 -0.300000 0.0300000 0.199550 
0.00000 0.00000 0.0100000 0.200000 
-2.00000 0.300000 -0.0100000 0.200450 
-4.00000 0.500000 -0.0300000 0.200750 
-6.02000 0.800000 -0.0502000 0.201200 
-8.00000 1.10000 -0.0700000 0.201650 
-10.0000 1.30000 -0.0900000 0.201950 
-12.0300 1.50000 -0.110300 0.202250 
-13.9800 1.80000 -0.129800 0.202700
```

---

The `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:18]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Current mA}, ylabel={Voltage mV}]

\addplot[mark size=1.5, only marks,
      error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both, y explicit,
        x dir=both, x explicit
      ]
      table [x error index=2, y error index=3]
      {data.csv};
   \addplot[no markers,color=blue,forget plot]
    table [y={create col/linear regression={y=1}}]
    {data.csv}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why is there need to print the data when referencing the file?

Comment: @Magpie: Do you mean the `\begin{filecontents}...\end{filecontents}` section? That's only a way for LaTeX to pretend that that file exists in the file system. In a real application, you'd have the `data.csv` in the file system, and you wouldn't use the `filecontents` bit.

Comment: Oh. that was confusing me. I tried using file cotents with just the file but it wouldn't read the error columns?

Comment: @Magpie: is everything working now?

Comment: No I probably shouldn't have clicked yes. I get what you are saying though I did it another way because I can't get that way to work. I'd like to be able to though becuase it's annoying having to post the file contents, I just tried your code as is. I'll unclick the answer and show you what I get from it and what's in the file -maybe you will know straight away what I have done wrongly.

Comment: @Magpie: Sorry for begin unclear: Remove *everything* that has to do with `filecontents` if you have the file on your file system. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Does it need the titles to be in the files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7325/discussion-between-jake-and-magpie)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I have found but it would be preferable to use Jake's (if I can get it working, that is)

```
\pgfplotstableread{
Current Voltage xerr   yerr     
13.9800 7.50000 0.149800 0.211250 
12.0300 6.50000 0.130300 0.209750 
10.0000 5.40000 0.110000 0.208100 
8.00000 4.30000 0.0900000 0.206450 
6.02000 3.20000 0.0702000 0.204800 
4.00000 2.20000 0.0500000 0.203300 
2.00000 1.10000 0.0300000 0.201650 
0.00000 0.00000 0.0100000 0.200000 
-2.00000 -1.10000 -0.0100000 0.198350 
-3.99000 -2.20000 -0.0299000 0.196700 
-6.01000 -3.30000 -0.0501000 0.195050 
-8.00000 -4.30000 -0.0700000 0.193550 
-9.99000 -5.40000 -0.0899000 0.191900 
-12.0300 -6.50000 -0.110300 0.190250 
-13.9700 -7.40000 -0.129700 0.188900 
}\wfp

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={ymode=log}]{regression}{\wfp}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=2.2,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,xlabel={Current $mA$}, ylabel={Voltage $mV$},title={$V_H$ against current for p-type Germanium}
]

\addplot [only marks, black, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, y explicit, x explicit, error bar style={color=mapped color}]
      table[x=Current,y=Voltage,x error=xerr,y error=yerr]{\wfp}; % plot the data
%\addplot [no markers, domain=0:18] {exp(\intercept+\slope*x)}; 
\addplot [color=blue, domain=-15:15, mark=none] {-0.00143422 + 0.537833 *\x};



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The resizing was acheived using the scale=2.2 with the package `\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}`